# add images dynamically created div to show text

Tags: jquery, html, css

onClick() event of Images I want to create div dynamically and add images to that div. dynamicaly created should have background color and some text please help.

this is Updated Fiddle with Flip method  http://jsfiddle.net/RQ62f/7/

```
#foobar
{
    background-color: red;
content: div is here;   
}

 in Jquery,
 $(this).appendTo('#foobar');
```

Please help

Comment: when I run the jsfiddle, the image can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery:

```
 $("img").click(function(){
 alert('m called');
 if ($('#foobar').length==0) $('<div id="foobar"></div>').appendTo('body');
   $(this).appendTo('#foobar');

 });
```

An element must exist in order to append something to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

http://jsfiddle.net/RQ62f/8/

```
 $("img").click(function(){
     $("body").append("<div id='foobar'></div>")
       $(this).appendTo('#foobar');
 });
```

P.S. In your fiddle, you didn't include the jQuery file